# Sitecore FXM needs port 80 open?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-fxm

We are trying to change header and footer of a site using Sitecore FXM. For security reasons, port 80 on the target server is blocked. Thus we get a "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ServerIP:80".

Both My Sitecore Url and Target URL are open on port number 443. Isn't this sufficient? Do we still need port 80 open on target server?

I'm using Sitecore 8.2.6 update to use FXM with local mongo DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Sitecore documentation below you do need **port 80**

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/configuring/the_requirements_and_limitations_of_fxm?roles=admin